# DC shunt motor losses

Tags: motor

Good morning I have been asked the question to name as many losses as you can in a DC shunt motor and state weather these will increase or decrease with increased load.

Now I have had a look at various books and websites but I can't seen to find what I am looking for. I have identified the various losses but am unsure of where to look to see if they increase or decrease or  remain constant when load is increased.

Heres my shot at it anyway

Increase= Energy loss, copper loss, core loss, mechanical loss, (windage)
Decrease= Brush losses
Constant= Magnetic losses, (hysterisis, Eddy current) Stray losses

Can anybody offer any comment on these might be completely wrong?

Thanks Jamie

Comment: Apologies this should have been for a dc shunt motor i will edit the post to show this. I assume the losses shoukd be fairly similar for all motor types though?

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the load to a series motor at constant input voltage (an assumption about supply voltage was not stated in your question, the answers will be different if we make a different assumption, like voltage is increased to keep the speed constant), then the current goes up, and along with it the magnetic field swing occuring in both the stator iron and the armature iron, and the speed goes down.

Therefore the losses that rise are those proportional to current, and to magnetic field.

The losses that drop are those proportional to speed.

Have another look at your list of losses, some of them are correct.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply Neil the experiment was to increase torque required with an appied fixed supply voltage of and record the values of Vf,If,Va,ia. Then plot a graph of the various values. Looking at the armature current in this circuit i can see that it increases as more torque is required presumably to maintain speed am I correct in saying that in this case resistance will lower due to rise in current throughout the experiment

Comment: rise in current will make the copper hotter, and so increase its resistance, it has a +ve tempco, of 10% per 25C, few people realise how big the tempco is!